# checkbox not visible in any browser

Tags: html, css, checkbox

```
 <style>
    input[type="checkbox"]
    {
    -webkit-appearance: checkbox;

    }

</style>

<input type="checkbox" id="radio6" value="1" name="sports" />
```

I am stuck in this for quite a while. Please help

Comment: I can see. https://jsfiddle.net/zbhLhL2v/

Comment: open console and check error

Comment: any browser? Working in Chrome and FF. I hope you are not using IE 7. :D

Comment: which browser u r using?

Answer (score 0):

I checked on various browsers and it seems to be appearing just fine.

Check you complete CSS to see whether some style is making the input checkbox type display:none or visibility:hidden.

If not, then check your Javascript/jQuery. Sometimes, they change the styling of some default elements.

Comment: Thanx @Aru .It was due to one of my jquey librabries